# Как можно узнать точный DataGridView?

Tags: c#, menu, база-данных

Добрый день! Динамически создается `ContextMenuStrip`, отдельно создаются различные его `Item` с разными обрабатываемыми методами. В программе много `DataGridView`.
Как по нажатию по `Item` какого-либо из созданных `ContextMenuStrip`, который, в свою очередь, привязан к какому-нибудь `DatGridView`, можно узнать точный `DataGridView`?

Спасибо!

Comment: @Станислав Кузнецов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Можно в этих свойствах покопаться (в зависимости от вложенности меню и т.д. может потребоваться раскрывать дальше, посмотрите в дебаге свойства sender на обработке клика по меню):

```
        var grid = ((DataGridView) ((ContextMenuStrip) (((ToolStripItem) (sender)).Owner)).SourceControl);
```